# I do not understand Haskell foldr

Tags: haskell

what does `mystery` do?

```
mystery xs = foldr f [] xs

f next soFar = soFar ++ [next]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I strongly believe this to be an homework question. Please provide what you have tried to do to solve the problems.

Comment: why the massive downvotes .. please keep the haskell community friendly here - even if it's homework that's no problem at all - just don't spoil everything at once in your answer - thanks

Answer (score 1):

no, `foldr f [] xs =/= []`. Let's see,

```
mystery xs 
  = foldr f [] xs 
  -- ( assuming xs == (x:t), i.e. non-empty: )
  = foldr f [] (x:t)
  -- ( by definition of `foldr`: )
  = f x (foldr f [] t)
  -- ( by definition of `mystery`: )
  = f x (mystery t)
  = mystery t ++ [x]
```

So, what does `mystery` do? What does it do with a list `[a,b,c]` for example?

```
mystery [a,b,c]
  = mystery [b,c] ++ [a]
  = (mystery [c] ++ [b]) ++ [a]
  = ((mystery [] ++ [c]) ++ [b]) ++ [a]
  = ...
```

You can complete the picture here.